# Fetching Django-comments from all sites for a given object

Tags: django, django-comments, django-sites

I am sharing objects between different sites using the Django-sites framework. This works fine because I was able to define a many-to-many relationship within my models.

However, while retrieving the comments (Django-comments) for the objects using the template tag 'render_comment_list', I only get those comments which where posted in that particular site. This is expected, but I would like also to get those other comments that were posted for that object which is shared among multiple sites.

Digging into the code of Django-comments, it seems that this is the method causing the 'problem':

```
def get_query_set(self, context):
    ctype, object_pk = self.get_target_ctype_pk(context)
    if not object_pk:
        return self.comment_model.objects.none()

    qs = self.comment_model.objects.filter(
        content_type = ctype,
        object_pk    = smart_unicode(object_pk),
        site__pk     = settings.SITE_ID,
    )
```

My questions are:

- What would be the easiest way to change the behavior so the template tag 'render_comment_list' displays all the comments for an object but not just the ones for a particular site?
- Do I need to create another template tag and copy & paste 99% of the Django-comments template tag code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to copy and past 99% of the template tag code, just subclass `RenderCommentListNode` and override the `get_queryset_method` where you identified the problem. Then copy the `render_comment_list` function, but use your child class.

```
class RenderCommentListNodeAllSites(RenderCommnetListNode):
    def get_query_set(self, context):
        ctype, object_pk = self.get_target_ctype_pk(context)
        if not object_pk:
            return self.comment_model.objects.none()

        qs = self.comment_model.objects.filter(
            content_type = ctype,
            object_pk    = smart_unicode(object_pk),
        )

def render_comment_list_all_sites(parser, token):
    return RenderCommentListNodeAllSites.handle_token(parser, token)
register.tag(render_comment_list_all_sites)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alasdair! I made the changes and it is working. Writing the whole code (now it works!) for clarity:

```
class RenderCommentListNodeAllSites(RenderCommentListNode):
    def get_query_set(self, context):
        ctype, object_pk = self.get_target_ctype_pk(context)
        if not object_pk:
            return self.comment_model.objects.none()

        qs = self.comment_model.objects.filter(
            content_type = ctype,
            object_pk    = smart_unicode(object_pk),
            #site__pk     = settings.SITE_ID,
        )

        # The is_public and is_removed fields are implementation details of the
        # built-in comment model's spam filtering system, so they might not
        # be present on a custom comment model subclass. If they exist, we
        # should filter on them.
        field_names = [f.name for f in self.comment_model._meta.fields]
        if 'is_public' in field_names:
            qs = qs.filter(is_public=True)
        if getattr(settings, 'COMMENTS_HIDE_REMOVED', True) and 'is_removed' in field_names:
            qs = qs.filter(is_removed=False)

        return qs

def render_comment_list_all_sites(parser, token):
    return RenderCommentListNodeAllSites.handle_token(parser, token)
register.tag(render_comment_list_all_sites)
```